# Once I have a base64 url how can I change the filter for brightness and contrast?

Tags: javascript, typescript, image-processing, css-filters

If I have an image in base64 ex.

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDAAwfqNRk/rjcYX+PxrV/wtWqwJSTlboMgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

What's the fastest way to change a filter (ex. brightness, contrast) programmatically and without creating any img or canvas tag in the view? Then once changed, convert it back to a base64 url?

Comment: I would give this a try https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-filters and instead of URL pass the data:image/png;base64 and see what happens!

Comment: Do you know if I can get this to work in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting the image onto a HTML canvas with filters applied, then turning that canvas back into a base64 URL.

Since you never add the canvas to the document, it will never be seen.

This is how you would do it asynchronously:
This takes about 1-10ms

```
function applyFiltersToImage(imageURL, callBack) {
    // load the image url into an image object
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = imageURL;

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image.onload = () => {        
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        // apply css filters here
        ctx.filter = 'brightness(0.5) contrast(2)';

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
        // turn canvas back into a base64 image URL
        callBack(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    }
}
```

You could do it synchronously if you already have the Image instance loaded.

This is how you will do it synchronously:

```
function applyFiltersToImageSync(imageObject) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
    canvas.width = imageObject.width;
    canvas.height = imageObject.height;

    // apply css filters here
    ctx.filter = 'brightness(0.5) contrast(2)';

    ctx.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //turn canvas back into a base64 image
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "You could do it synchronously if you already have the Image instance loaded."? FYI - I'm using a cropper util to crop the image first then the output I get from the cropper util is the base64 string like in my post above. At this point I need to apply brightness or contrast. Then get the base64 string back to send to a image storing service in the cloud.

Comment: I think I'll need to do it synchronously, how would that look different than what you provided?

Comment: To put an image onto a canvas, you need to add an image object. You can turn an base64 image url into an image object by creating an instance of the Image class (new Image()), then setting the src property to the base64 URL.
This image object needs time to load before it can be used, thus the image.onload. This means that the code will run asynchronously and you cant return the new base64 URL, you will have to use a callback or promise. If you already have created and loaded this image object, which it seems like you have if you previously crop it, then you don't have to wait for it to load.